# No view found for id 0x7f080032 for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

Hi I have tried a lot to find a solution and tried a lot of different ones (that were in `Java`) but none worked for me, my approach is also a bit different than those already on `Stackoverflow` so that's why I have to ask the question again.

I will try to shortly explain what I am doing,
I have a `MainActivity` that has a `BottomNavigationView` that contains 5 `Fragments`.

In one of these (`ManageTasksFragment`) I have a `ViewPager` that has 2 tabs (two child Fragments) `ManageGivenFragment` and `ManageDoingFragment`, so far so good.

> ManageTasksFragment.kt

```
private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_tasks, container, false)
    //val indicator = view.findViewById(R.id.tpi_header) as TabPageIndicator
    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.manage_tasks_tab_layout)
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.manage_tasks_view_pager)

    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val sectionPageAdapter = SectionPageAdapter(childFragmentManager)
    // Adding Fragments
    sectionPageAdapter.addFragment(ManageGivenFragment(), "Given")
    sectionPageAdapter.addFragment(ManageDoingFragment(), "Doing")
    //adapter Setup
    viewPager.adapter = sectionPageAdapter
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
}
```

Now I have a new fragment called `ManageGivenDetailsFragment` that is supposed to be the child of `ManageGivenFragment`, but when I try to replace the fragment the app crashes and I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080032 (it.dobeedo.dobeedo:id/container) for fragment ManageGivenDetailsFragment
```

> ManageGivenFragment.kt

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val tasksArray = DataViewModel.instance.dataSource
    //val openTasksArray = removeDoneTasks(tasksArray)
    val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.manage_given_tasks_recyclerView)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)


    adapter = ManageGivenTasksAdapter(tasksArray, context!!) { item ->

        val manageGivenTaskDetailsFragment = ManageGivenDetailsFragment()
        //manageGivenTaskDetailsFragment.selectedTask = item
        //fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.container, manageGivenTaskDetailsFragment)?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()
        this.childFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.container, manageGivenTaskDetailsFragment)?.commit()
    }
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
```

In the code above I have tried both `fragmentManager` and `childFragmentManager`.

ManageGivenDetailsFragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_given_details, null, false)
}
```

in the code above I tried both `null` and `container` as the `root` for `inflater`, since someone suggested to change this to `null` but still didn't work.

If you need more code of a specific part please let me know, I would be glad to get help from you.

**UPDATE**

> MainActivity.kt

```
lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar

private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> {
            toolbar.title = "Home"
            val homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(homeFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_manage_tasks -> {
            toolbar.title = "Manage Tasks"
            val manageTasksFragment = ManageTasksFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(manageTasksFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_add_tasks -> {
            //toolbar.title = "Add Task"
            val addTaskFragment = AddTaskFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(addTaskFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_profile -> {
            //toolbar.title = "Profile"
            val profileFragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(profileFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.action_bar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    //toolbar = supportActionBar!!
    val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigation)
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

    //
    // Show the First Fragmnet on load - One time only
    //
    val manager = supportFragmentManager
    var fragment: Fragment? = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.container)

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = HomeFragment()
        manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).commit()
    }
}




private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="it.dobeedo.dobeedo.Activities.MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    layout="@layout/action_bar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigationView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/action_bar" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post your XML for `ManageGivenFragment`.

Comment: is id `container` is defined in `ManageGivenFragment` in `FrameLayout`

Comment: Where is your R.id.container

Comment: @ManojPatidar what do you mean defined? how?

Comment: @mducc in activity_main.xml

Comment: Move `R.id.container` to `ManageGivenFragment` layout XML and try again

Comment: @mducc I don't get it, how can I? I mean the whole app is using it, doesn't this break the other fragments if I bring it here?

Comment: You are use `childFragmentManager`, R.id.container is parent view, you will add `manageGivenTask DetailsFragment` to inside parent view, R.id.container should is view of fragment selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just call the activity from this Fragment, replace

```
this.childFragmentManager
```

with

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager
```

So you should have:

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.container, manageGivenTaskDetailsFragment)?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I am assuming that `R.id.container` is in mainactivity.java
Due to this managegivenfragment cannot reach it and so you are getting no view found.

```
this.childFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.container, manageGivenTaskDetailsFragment)?.commit()
```

replace `R.id.container` with below

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container).getId()
```

If above doesn't work, post your mainactivity code.

Comment: Please answer this

You have R.id.container in R.layout.mainActivity file, right?

If yes then You can't access parent activity XML element from a fragment by using R.id.the_element

Answer above and we can discuss how to solve this.

Comment: Yes the containter is in main_activity.xml

Comment: Exactly so post one last thing
Please post main_activity.xml

Comment: I think this should work (but I'll be more sure if I have the XML file)
BTW I'm proficient in java so you'll have to format the code to kotlin though the logic will be exactly the same since Google made sure java and kotlin have same logic but different syntax
            ________
val container = view.findViewById<Fragment *I dont know what you used for container* >(R.id.container)
val containerID = container.getId()
this.childFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(containerID, manageGivenTaskDetailsFragment)?.commit()

Comment: Hey, I did that but I'm getting null again, this value container that I defined now, is null so I can't reach it's id. I have added the layout of my mainActivity.

Comment: Yeah we get a null because the variable view contains ManageTasksFragment's layout and that layout doesn't have container.

Comment: This is my final shot. I'm trying to write in kotlin but do check the syntax once before running. val container = getActivity().findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.container) val containerID = container.getId() this.childFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(containerID, manageGivenTaskDetailsFragment)?.commit()

Comment: What is the error you get? Copy and paste it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

It's may be because you are trying to access the fragment's view, before activity layout inintialization i.e. In android once activity created then only we can access its fragment layout. So simply **remove the code from onCreateView() and copy it to onActivityCreated()**, as following.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     //make variable 'view' to global and access it
     tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.manage_tasks_tab_layout)
     viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.manage_tasks_view_pager)
}
```

Comment: why are you using fragment for detailed view ??(i.e. **make ManageGivenDetailsFragment as Activity instead of fragment**) , so it will be better for back navigation. **OR**  instead of this.childFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?... try getActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()...